# Einstein: Chart Field Order Different than SAQL

Tags: salesforce-einstein

I created a SAQL query that had Region and Country (custom fields).  I'm then doing a bit of ranking of spending by country within a region.  When I create the chart back in the dashboard it shows Country then Region, which makes no sense since I'm doing the rank.  Why was the order flipped?  The saql clearly has Region then Country.  Can I override this?